# Display WebSocket message with formatting?

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, formatting, signalr, google-chrome-devtools

**UPDATE**: At time of asking this question, this was related to SignalR library and not plain WebSockets. I see correctly formatted messages now.

---

Is there any way to word-wrap messages in `WS` tab in Chrome Developer Tools or display `JSON` with formatting ? It's really annoying to scroll to right to see whole message.

Example with message selected and it's preview doesn't have any formatting or word wrapping applied:

[image: Web Sockets example]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine here on `Chrome/78.0.3904.97`:

[image: Screenshot]

What I did:

1. Go to http://crawl.develz.org/play.htm
2. Open one of the listed servers
3. Start devtools
4. Go to the Application tab and [add a cookie](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies#edit) called "no-compression" with value "yeah no" to the relevant server. (Any truthy string should work, I just chose the least confusing one I could think of in about a minute.)

   - Otherwise, crawl's webtiles server can end up compressing messages even when browser supports [RFC 7692's `"permessage-deflate"`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692#section-7) extension, which ruins the demonstration.
5. Open the Network tab
6. Reload the page
7. Select the "socket" request, switch to the "Messages" tab, and pick a frame.
8. Start drilling down in the tree view in the bottom pane!

Comment: I now know why I don't get representation as JSON. At the end of my JSON, there is a control character, the red dot (`\u1e`). That's why I didn't get formatting properly. You can see it in picture I posted as rectangle at end of JSON.

Comment: @DinkoPehar Were you able to get JSON formatting working with the control character present?

Comment: @Gili No, I still had to scroll.

Comment: I got json representation for any site. But not XML representation and not even line wrap. Sometimes the messages are so big, it is super hard to read that.

Comment: @DinkoPehar Any luck with removal of this control character?

Comment: Hi @ToM . I worked with this long time ago. It was SignalR library from Microsoft for Websockets. It was a protocol on top of WebSockets, so I assume that was something due to that (because it was new or something). I just found examples online with working SignalR implementation http://philssignalrdemo.azurewebsites.net/ and I have correct messages shown.

Comment: @DinkoPehar I'm also using SignalR from MS Azure right now and see exactly the same issue.